# State not updating immediately

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a web app that calculates BMR by asking the user for age, weight, gender, feet, inches. After the user submits the form, there should be an alert box with the state of all objects. The only problem is, BMR is the only one that stays at 0; it doesn't update until I click submit again. I am working with two Classes: Macros(main) and Form. My code is below

```
class Macros extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        age: '',
        weight: '',
        male: true,
        feet: '',
        inches: '',
        BMR: 0,
    };

    this.handleAgeChange = this.handleAgeChange.bind(this);
    this.handleWeightChange = this.handleWeightChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleGenderChange = this.handleGenderChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFeetChange = this.handleFeetChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInchChange = this.handleInchChange.bind(this);
    this.calculateBMR = this.calculateBMR.bind(this);
}

handleAgeChange(event) {
    this.setState({age: event.target.value});
}

handleWeightChange(event) {
    this.setState({weight: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    this.calculateBMR();
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Age: ' + this.state.age + ' Weight: ' + this.state.weight + ' Male: ' + this.state.male 
    + ' Feet: ' + this.state.feet + ' Inches: ' + this.state.inches + ' BMR: ' + this.state.BMR) 
}

handleGenderChange(event) {
    this.setState({male: !this.state.male});
}

handleFeetChange(event) {
    this.setState({feet: event.target.value});
}

handleInchChange(event) {
    this.setState({inches: event.target.value});
}

calculateBMR() {
    let calBMR = 0;
    if(this.state.male){
        calBMR = ((10 * ((this.state.weight) / 2.20462)) + 
            (6.25 * ((this.state.feet * 30.48) + (this.state.inches * 2.54))) - 
            (5 * this.state.age)) + 5;
    }
    else {
        calBMR = ((10 * ((this.state.weight) / 2.20462)) + 
            (6.25 * ((this.state.feet * 30.48) + (this.state.inches * 2.54))) - 
            (5 * this.state.age)) - 161;
    }
    this.setState({BMR: calBMR});
}


render(){
    const title = 'Macro Apps';
    const subtitle = 'Calculate Your Macro-Nutrient Intake for Flexible Dieting';
    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={title} subtitle={subtitle} />
            <Form onAgeChange={this.handleAgeChange} onWeightChange={this.handleWeightChange}
                  onGenderChange={this.handleGenderChange} onFeetChange={this.handleFeetChange}
                  onInchChange={this.handleInchChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<Macros />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Form Class

```
import React from 'react';

export class Form extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
                    Age:
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.props.onAgeChange}/><br />
                    Weight:
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.props.onWeightChange} /><br />
                    <label>
                    <input 
                        type="radio"
                        name="gender"
                        checked="checked"
                        onChange={this.props.onGenderChange}
                    />
                    Male
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input 
                        type="radio"
                        name="gender"
                        onChange={this.props.onGenderChange}
                    />
                    Female<br/>
                </label>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.props.onFeetChange}/>ft 
                <input type="text" onChange={this.props.onInchChange}/>in<br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Given that this a complete solution - could you post it into a codesandbox? Here is the react template https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: Done. https://codesandbox.io/s/7k3xxlkv26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ReactJS setting state is asynchronous. You can simply pass a `callback` to `setState` method like this:

`setState({ "something": "needs to change" }, () => { /* will be invoked when the state changes. */ })`

So this lines of code:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    this.calculateBMR();
    ...
}

calculateBMR() {
    ...
    this.setState({BMR: calBMR});
}
```

Could be look like this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    this.calculateBMR(() => {
         alert('Age: ' + this.state.age + ' Weight: ' + this.state.weight + ' Male: ' + this.state.male + 
         ' Feet: ' + this.state.feet + ' Inches: ' + this.state.inches + ' BMR: ' + this.state.BMR) 
    });
}

calculateBMR(callback) {
    this.setState({ BMR: calBMR }, callback);
}
```

Comment: Great! Question, if I click the female radio button and then click submit; shortly after the alert box goes away the radio button switches to male. How do I avoid it switching to male so it's not misleading for the user ?

Comment: Well it's happening because of you are keeping the state of "form inputs" but you are not populating form from this state, instead of this you are rendering a static form that has no state at all. You can pass the states of weight, inches or feet to children component ( which is `Form` ) as props and use them in there like this: `<input type="text" onChange={this.props.onAgeChange} value={this.props.age}/>` You can pass them like: `<Form onAgeChange={..smth} ... age={this.state.age} />`

Answer (score 0):

you can change like below or try to use Mobx

```
`class Macros extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        age: '',
        weight: '',
        male: true,
        feet: '',
        inches: '',
        BMR: 0,
    };

    this.handleAgeChange = this.handleAgeChange.bind(this);
    this.handleWeightChange = this.handleWeightChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleGenderChange = this.handleGenderChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFeetChange = this.handleFeetChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInchChange = this.handleInchChange.bind(this);
    this.calculateBMR = this.calculateBMR.bind(this);
}

handleAgeChange(event) {
    this.setState({age: event.target.value},this.calculateBMR);
}

handleWeightChange(event) {
    this.setState({weight: event.target.value},this.calculateBMR);
}

handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Age: ' + this.state.age + ' Weight: ' + this.state.weight + ' Male: ' + this.state.male 
    + ' Feet: ' + this.state.feet + ' Inches: ' + this.state.inches + ' BMR: ' + this.state.BMR) 
}

handleGenderChange(event) {
    this.setState({male: !this.state.male},this.calculateBMR);
}

handleFeetChange(event) {
    this.setState({feet: event.target.value},this.calculateBMR);
}

handleInchChange(event) {
    this.setState({inches: event.target.value},this.calculateBMR);
}

calculateBMR() {
    let calBMR = 0;
    if(this.state.male){
        calBMR = ((10 * ((this.state.weight) / 2.20462)) + 
            (6.25 * ((this.state.feet * 30.48) + (this.state.inches * 2.54))) - 
            (5 * this.state.age)) + 5;
    }
    else {
        calBMR = ((10 * ((this.state.weight) / 2.20462)) + 
            (6.25 * ((this.state.feet * 30.48) + (this.state.inches * 2.54))) - 
            (5 * this.state.age)) - 161;
    }
    this.setState({BMR: calBMR});
}


render(){
    const title = 'Macro Apps';
    const subtitle = 'Calculate Your Macro-Nutrient Intake for Flexible Dieting';
    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={title} subtitle={subtitle} />
            <Form onAgeChange={this.handleAgeChange} onWeightChange={this.handleWeightChange}
                  onGenderChange={this.handleGenderChange} onFeetChange={this.handleFeetChange}
                  onInchChange={this.handleInchChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<Macros />, document.getElementById('root'));
`
```